# Emmet overwriting the text next to it

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, replace, overwrite

In vs code in html, Emmet is overwriting or replacing text. For example,
(p)My name is Prakash.(p)

Now in the above line I want to make the word "Prakash" in bold. For that I put the cursor before the word "P". Then I type (b and Emmet suggestions show up. I choose "bold" from the suggestions. Now the problem happens. The bold tag instead of pushing the word "Prakash" to the right, overwrites on the word "Prakash".

Help me solve the problem. (Note:- Understand the brackets as angular brackets.I couldnt find angular brackets on my mobile to type here)

I have described the problem in the best way possible. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: use **Wrap with abbreviation** command

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.